# Is that possible to use our Virtual Machines instead of Batch Services in Data Factory?

Tags: .net, sdk, virtual-machine, azure-data-factory, custom-activity

I am using **Batch Services** for Data Factory Custom Activity but I want to use separate my **Virtual Machine** instead of Batch Services.

```
{
"name": "AzureBatchLinkedService",
"properties": {
"type": "AzureBatch",
"typeProperties": {
 "accountName": "myazurebatchaccount",
 "batchUri": "https://westus.batch.azure.com",
 "accessKey": "<yourbatchaccountkey>",
 "poolName": "myazurebatchpool",
 "linkedServiceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService"
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it's only possible to run custom activity on Azure Batch or on HDInsight (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities)).

However, you Azure Batch Account is based on pool of virtual machines anyway. You can create Batch Account with pool which consists of only one VM - your predefined instance.

Follow [Create Batch Account Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-account-create-portal), but on 3rd step you need to select `User Subscription` pool allocation modes. That means that used VMs will belong to subscription, not to Batch Service.

Comment: Is there any other Documentation for step by step procedure ?

Comment: @Arron I've added link into answer